# MockClient 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, testing, mockito, httprequest

I'm trying to create some tests for flutter app with Mockito.

This is my code:

```
@GenerateMocks([http.Client])
main() {
  group('sendUrlPost', () {
    test('returns alias and links if the post call is successful', () async {
      final client = MockClient();
      String apiUrl = "someApiURL";
      String longUrl = "someUrl";
      when(client.post(Uri.parse(apiUrl),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: jsonEncode(
              {"url": longUrl}))).thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(
          '{"alias":"70492","_links":{"self":"https://www.youtube.com","short":"https://url-shortener-nu.herokuapp.com/short/70492"}}',
          200));
      expect(await UrlPostConnector.sendUrlPost(longUrl), isA<UrlResponse>());
    });
  });
}
```

I have followed exactly what the official guide has:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking
but when I create the mock client  I get the following error:

final client = MockClient();

> 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding the
> missing arguments

[image]

I'm guessing the guide is outdated but I haven't found a way to make it work. I would apprecieate if you can tellme what I'm doing wrong and if there is a better way to test an Http request.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're using `package:http`'s [`MockClient` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient/MockClient.html)  instead (which you ought to be using anyway instead of mocking it yourself). However, I'm not sure how that would be possible unless you both 1. Neglected to `import` the generated `.mocks.dart` file and 2. `import` `package:http` with and without an `http` prefix.

Comment: you're right, I was missing the generated mocks.dart. running flutter pub run build_runner build solved the issue.  Thanks

Comment: But anyway, [I strongly advise against manually mocking `http.Client` and using its own `MockClient` class instead](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/6924).

Comment: So it's better to approach it like this example instead?:
https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/http.testing-library.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the generated mocks.dart file that is created by running

```
 flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Thanks to @jamesdlin for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you added the annotation to generate the mock

```
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
```

then `@GenerateMocks([http.Client])`

In the terminal: `dart run build_runner build`

import the generated file **unit_test.mocks.dart**

There may be a conflict between your local **unit_test.mocks.dart** file and the MockClient class present in the **package:http package.**

Since both files have classes with the same name `MockClient`, Dart gets confused about which one to use.

**Solution**:

Rename your local `MockClient` class to a unique name, for example, `MyMockClient`.
Update your code to use the newly named class (e.g., `final MyMockClient client = MyMockClient();`).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to lower down the version to `5.0.0`

```
mockito: ^5.0.0
```

Make sure you run this command after creating test class

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```